# How to use system.setStorage()?

Tags: polkadot-js, storage, vesting-balance

Context: I need to put some data on vesting pallet. There is no such things as `setVestedStorage`, so I need to use `system.setStorage` (`api.tx.system.storage` for the complete form) from the polkadotjs API

The problem is that I can't find ANY documentation on this function, the only thing i know is it's interface: `setStorage(Vec<Bytes, Bytes>)`, and that the first bytes parameter are the "old bytes", and the second the "new bytes" (according to the only appearance of `setStorage` in [substrate github repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/search?q=setStorage)), but that's all.

How do I get the old bytes ?
How do I get the new bytes ? Especially as I use the function in a js script.
How am I supposed to call this function ?
Do I have to call it multiple times if I have an enormous amount of data (200k entries), or can I call it a single time ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, which docs this is referring to. But this would be the extrinsic that is called https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L442.

So it’s rather a Key and a Value to set in storage. In your case you would need to set the key and the value accordingly to the vesting storage-map (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/frame/vesting/src/lib.rs#L194).

Hope this helps.